# Why default constructor cannot handle exception type Exception?

Tags: java, exception, inheritance, constructor

I want to know that why i have to define an explict constructor because i am getting error which says that default constructor cannot handle exception type Exception thrown by implicit super constructor.

```
class A {
    A() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("A Class");
    }
}

public class Example extends A {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Example t = new Example();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @JonK Apparently it's "Why do I have to define an explicit constructor? I'm getting these errors when I don't define one".

Comment: @FUZxxl It looks like a question has been edited in since I made that comment - originally it was an error message and a code dump.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - your `Example` class is *effectively* declaring:

```
public Example() {
    super();
}
```

That won't compile, because the `super()` call is calling the `A()` constructor which is declared to throw `Exception`, which is a checked exception. That's just as much a mistake in a constructor as it is to call a method which declares that it throws a checked exception from within a method which neither catches the exception nor declares that it throws it itself.

So you need to declare the exception in an *explicitly* declared constructor in `Example`.

```
public Example() throws Exception {
    super(); // This is implicit; you can remove it if you want.
}
```

instead. Note that this is only relevant if the constructor throws a *checked* exception... unchecked exceptions don't need to be declared, so the "compiler-provided" default exception is fine.

Also note that you can't *catch* an exception thrown by a super-constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an explicit constructor with `throws` clause to the Example class.

```
public Example() throws Exception {
}
```