# Unable to import a connection from a different class

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to create a library that helps accessing data from database and will be used in the future for another app. However I think I messed up somewhere and I wasn't able to import the Connection defined in the class database to class features. The error it throws back at me is

> Default constructor cannot handle exception type Exception thrown by Implicit constructor. Must define an explicit constructor.

1)

```
public class database {

    public static String databaseName;
    public static String username;
    public static String password;
    public String tableName;
    public String schema;
    public String query;
    ResultSet rs;
    public static Connection dbconnection;

    public database(String databaseName, String username, String password) throws Exception {
        this.databaseName = databaseName;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public database() throws Exception{
        databaseName = "database";
        username = "admin";
        password = "12345";
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    // Connect to selected Cache Database
    public static Connection connect() throws Exception {
        try {
            // Default port is 1972
            String url = "jdbc:Cache://127.0.0.1:1972/" + databaseName;
            Class.forName("com.intersys.jdbc.CacheDriver").newInstance();
            dbconnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            System.out.println("Connected to " + databaseName + " database.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dbconnection;
    }
}
```

2)

```
public class features {
    database db = new database();
    Connection conn = db.connect();
    ResultSet rs;
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Put your code inside a method. Not directly inside the class. This isn't valid Java. Also, learn and respect the Java naming conventions, and stop throwing Exception. Throw a well-identified, precise sub-type of Exception (or, in your case, no exception at all, since none of your instructions throw an exception). Also, initializing static fields from a constructor makes no sense at all. You also need to learn what is a static field, and what is an instance field.

Answer (score 0):

Your `database` class already has a connection and a resultset variable, why do you put another connection and resultset in class `features` ?, you should handle the connection in only one class, there is no need for two connections since you are only connecting to one database

Also there is no need for the `throws Exception` in every method, i think this should work for you:

**database**

```
public class database {

    public static String databaseName;
    public static String username;
    public static String password;
    public String tableName;
    public String schema;
    public String query;
    ResultSet rs;
    public static Connection dbconnection;
    public Statement st;

    public database(String databaseName, String username, String password) {
        this.databaseName = databaseName;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public database(){
        databaseName = "database";
        username = "admin";
        password = "12345";
        dbconnection=connect();
        st= dbconnection.createStatement();
    }

    // Connect to selected Cache Database
    public static Connection connect() {
        try {
            // Default port is 1972
            String url = "jdbc:Cache://127.0.0.1:1972/" + databaseName;
            Class.forName("com.intersys.jdbc.CacheDriver").newInstance();
            dbconnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            System.out.println("Connected to " + databaseName + " database.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dbconnection;
    }
}
```

**features**

```
public class features {
    public static database db;
    public ResultSet rs;

    public features (){
    db= new database();
    }

}
```

I made a couple changes to your code:

- Removed the variable `conn` from your class `features` since theres already a connection in the class `database`
- Moved the Statement variable `st` to the class `database` because you will be handling the connectiong in that class
- Modified the class `features` a bit by adding a constructor since you where declaring the variables and initializing them right away withoud using a constructor

The fixes I did should remove the error,I didn't have the time to check for syntax errors in the code so thats up to you but I think it should work just fine, The error was ocurring because you where throwing Exceptions in the methods of the class `database` and not handling them in the class `features`, for more info regarding this error you can check this question asked by another user regarding your same error:

[Why default constructor cannot handle exception type Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735703/why-default-constructor-cannot-handle-exception-type-exception)